# Large R dataframe - How to efficiently caculate a column

Tags: r

I have a dataframe in R that has numeric columns named X.new, X.old, X.delta;Y.new, Y.old, Y.detal and so on.  I have more than 100 columns with similar naming.  I want the delta columns to be calculated as new minus old  for similar names.  For example X.delta should be calculated as X.new-X.old for each row of the dataframe.  I have about a million rows.   Currently I have a loop to do this but I know it’s not the most efficient way.  Can I do this using purr or any other package more efficiently?  Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: looping over *columns* should not be too bad, as long as you don't loop over rows. `data.table` might help.  Can you give us current timings - i.e., how long does your current approach take?

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty general way to accomplish what you requested:

First some dummy data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  x.old = runif(1000),
  x.new = runif(1000),
  y.old = runif(1000),
  y.new = runif(1000)
)
```

Extract the prefixes by grepping the word before each `.`

```
pfx <- unique(gsub("(^..*)\\...*$", "\\1", names(df)))
pfx <- setNames(pfx, paste0(pfx, ".delta"))
```

Loop over each of the prefixes and use them to index the original data.frame columns and calculate your delta. These kinds of loops are fine in R.

```
deltas <- lapply(pfx, function(col) {
  old <- paste0(col, ".old")
  new <- paste0(col, ".new")
  df[[new]] - df[[old]]
})
```

Add the deltas to your original dataset:

```
res <- cbind(df, deltas)

> head(res)
       x.old      x.new      y.old     y.new    x.delta    y.delta
1 0.16582237 0.65722478 0.69491911 0.0321141  0.4914024 -0.6628050
2 0.31899968 0.86988894 0.63381341 0.3421112  0.5508893 -0.2917022
3 0.27247366 0.52519659 0.08306147 0.9015832  0.2527229  0.8185217
4 0.04901993 0.26079681 0.79428604 0.9277292  0.2117769  0.1334432
5 0.14126815 0.03030174 0.54559952 0.9441938 -0.1109664  0.3985943
6 0.21614648 0.03249826 0.90492169 0.1399136 -0.1836482 -0.7650081
```

Comment: Worked like a charm.  Thank you very much.